# PHP Register Code Not Working

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, jquery

The code below is meant to insert values into a MySQL Database if the passwords match, the username or email isn't used already. This code is called from ajax on another page. When it is called, the page redirects me to register.php instead of being completed on the backend by ajax. Does anybody see any issues that could be causing this? It doesn't give me any errors, just a blank white page.

```
$user = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['user'], ENT_QUOTES));
$pass = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['pass'], ENT_QUOTES));
$cpass = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['cpass'], ENT_QUOTES));
$age = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['age'], ENT_QUOTES));
$email = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['email'], ENT_QUOTES));
$country = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['count'], ENT_QUOTES));
$lang = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['lang'], ENT_QUOTES));
$mdpass = md5($pass);
$mdcpass = md5($cpass);
$created = Date("Y-m-d");


$result = mysql_query("SELECT username,email FROM tableName WHERE username = '$user'");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{
if ($row['username']>0) {
    echo 'nvuname';
} 
elseif ($row['email']>0)
{
    echo 'nvemail';
}
else
{
    if ($mdpass == $mdcpass && $age>>14) 
    {
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO tableName (username, pword, email,created,admin,rnumenab,autoreload,country,mailenab,updates,lang) VALUES ($user, $mdpass, $email, $created,'0','1','1',$country,'1','0',$lang)");
        echo 'success';
    }
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$("#regsubmit").click(function() {
    var action = $("#mainReg").attr('action');
    var form_data = {
        user: $("#user-reg").val(),
        pass: $("#pass-reg").val(),
        cpass: $("#cpass-reg").val(),
        email: $("#email").val(),
        age: $("#age").val()
    };
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: action,
        data: form_data,
        success: function(result)
        {
            if(result=='success') {
                $('#register-action').animate({
                    opacity : '-=1',
                    bottom : '-=60%'
                    }, 600);
                $('#register-action-bckgnd').hide();
                $('.message').fadeOut(600);
            } else {
                $('.regerror').fadeIn(600);
            }
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Thanks, and if you see any issues please let me know. Thank you so much!

Also:How do I sanitize my inputs so no HTML tags are included or did the strip_tags do that? Thanks.

EDIT: It now works and submits the page doesn't reload, but it always returns error instead of success even if I am sure I am using an open email, username. Turns out I had ('$age') instead of ('#age'). Ideas?

Comment: While your question is not unclear, the quality of it is low because there is more code than question, making it look as if you want us to do your work. Consider stripping any unrelated parts out of the code, or improving the question itself. *"Here's my code, please fix it for me"* usually doesn't work here.

Comment: @TomvanderWoerdt I removed anything unnecessary

Comment: You clearly want `$age > 14` instead of `$age >> 14` (the latter is a bit-shift)

Comment: What does the javascript look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I have not seen your javascript, when an ajax call results in a blank page, that normally means the page is being posted normally and not (only...) by ajax.

You will need to add something like

```
event.preventDefault();
```

or

```
return false;
```

to your javascript click / submit function.

**Edit:** Without seeing the html, you are using a click-handler and although that click-handler may return false, that does not mean that the form does not get submitted normally. I would attach the javascript to the form submit-handler instead and prevent the submit.

Comment: @Joseph Torraca Sounds like it's being submitted: `When it is called, the page redirects me to register.php instead of being completed on the backend by ajax`.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a normal button instead of a submit button e.g.

```
<button id="regsubmit">register</button>
```

instead of :

```
<input type="submit" id="regsubmit" value="register" />
```

OR you can do something like `$("form-seletor").submit(function(){ return false; });`